# AWS CodeCommit Error: git: 'credential-aws' is not a git command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-codecommit, git-for-windows

I am new to [Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/) world, and I am implementing [Continuous Delivery](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/set-up-ci-cd-pipeline/) to the company I work for.

I followed AWS's [instructions to configure CodeCommit Service] (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-https-windows.html#setting-up-https-windows-account)

**Step 1: Initial Configuration for [AWS CodeCommit](https://aws.amazon.com/codecommit/)**

*To create and configure an [IAM user](https://aws.amazon.com/iam/) for accessing [AWS CodeCommit](https://aws.amazon.com/codecommit/)*:
I created a new IAM user and gave him [AWSCodeCommitFullAccess](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/auth-and-access-control-iam-identity-based-access-control.html)

*To install and configure the AWS CLI* :

I installed and configured the credentials doing [*aws configure*](https://aws.amazon.com/config/#:%7E:text=AWS%20Config%20is%20a%20service,recorded%20configurations%20against%20desired%20configurations.).
Setting AWS Access Key ID, AWS Secret Access Key, Default region name to `us-east-1` and `de`

**Step 2: Install Git** 
I installed [Git For Windows](https://git-scm.com/downloads) making sure the Enable Git Credential Manager option was cleared.

**Step 3: Set Up the Credential Helper**

```
git config --global credential.helper "!aws codecommit credential-helper $@"
git config --global credential.UseHttpPath true
```

Executing:

```
git config --global --edit
```

My Configuration is:

```
[http]
  sslVerify = false
[credential]<br> 
  helper = "aws codecommit list-repositories codecommit credential-helper "
  UseHttpPath = true
```

**Step 4: Connect to the [AWS CodeCommit](https://aws.amazon.com/codecommit/) Console and Clone the Repository**

```
    $ git clone https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/teste-git-to-s3<br>
    Cloning into 'teste-git-to-s3'...<br>
    git: 'credential-aws' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.<br>
    Username for 'https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/teste-git-to-s3': Lucas<br>
    fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/teste-git-to-s3/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Looking for AWS troubleshooting, I found: [Troubleshooting AWS CodeCommit](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-ae1) but I couldn't solve it.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think the issue is in your .gitconfig file. Change it to below and it should work.

```
[credential]    
    helper = !aws codecommit credential-helper $@ 
    UseHttpPath = true
```

By the way, if you are using a Bash emulator instead of the Windows command line, you must use single quotes instead of double quotes.

Let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: Open a command prompt and use Git to run git config, specifying the use of the Git credential helper with the AWS credential profile, which enables the Git credential helper to send the path to repositories:

`git config --global credential.helper "!aws codecommit credential-helper $@"`

If you are using a Bash emulator instead of the Windows command line, you must use single quotes instead of double quotes.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-https-windows.html#setting-up-https-windows-credential-helper

Comment: I use ZSH and I had the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using *cygwin*, after you created the repository, click the connect info button, select linux instead of windows, it works on mine.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem with Python 3.8.x - make sure you are using Python 3.7.x instead, as shown in the docs